# Retrieving Data from Tkinter Window

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm

[image]

I created this tkinter window and created these drop down boxes.

```
        while number != (max+1):
            Subject1_Label = Label(master, text=("Subject", number))
            Subject1_Label.grid(row=number, column=0, pady=6)
            Subject1 = All_Subjects.get(number)
            variable = StringVar(master)
            variable.set(Subject1[0])
            w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *Subject1)
            w.grid(row=number, column=1, pady=6)
            subject_amount = subject_amount + 1
            number = number + 1
```

Usually to determine the input from the dropdown boxes I could simply use (variable.get) but in this case variable is being used 5 times to create 5 different boxes. Is there a way I can gather the input from these dropdown boxes using their position on the tkinter window. Such as (variable.get, row=1, column=1)? Or any other way?

Comment: You can store the variables in a list.

Comment: Not quite sure how exactly I would do that in this case, how would I actually retrieve 'math stand', english standard, 'chem', 'timber', and 'child studies' because they are created using the same variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `list` or `dictionary` to store the variables. Below is an example using `dictionary`:

```
variables = {}
while number != (max+1):
    subject = f"Subject {number}"
    Subject1_Label = Label(master, text=subject)
    Subject1_Label.grid(row=number, column=0, pady=6)
    Subject1 = All_Subjects.get(number)
    variable = StringVar(master)
    variable.set(Subject1[0])
    variables[subject] = variable  # save the variable
    w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *Subject1)
    w.grid(row=number, column=1, pady=6)
    subject_amount = subject_amount + 1
    number = number + 1
```

Then you can use something like `variables["Subject 1"].get()` to get the selected item of "Subject 1".

---

Update with an example:

```
from tkinter import *

# just for providing "All_Subjects.get(number)" in the while loop
class All_Subjects:
    subjects = ("math stand", "english standard", "chem", "timber", "child studies")
    def get(n):
        return All_Subjects.subjects

master = Tk()

max = 5
variables = {}
number = 1
subject_amount = 0
while number != (max+1):
    subject = f"Subject {number}"
    Subject1_Label = Label(master, text=subject)
    Subject1_Label.grid(row=number, column=0, pady=6)
    Subject1 = All_Subjects.get(number)
    variable = StringVar(master)
    variable.set(Subject1[0])
    variables[subject] = variable  # save the variable
    w = OptionMenu(master, variable, *Subject1)
    w.grid(row=number, column=1, pady=6)
    subject_amount = subject_amount + 1
    number = number + 1

def show_subjects():
    # use "Subject X" as key to get the selected subjects 
    for i in range(1, max+1):
        subject = f"Subject {i}"
        print(f"{subject}: {variables[subject].get()}")
    # or simply
    #print([var.get() for var in variables.values()])

Button(master, text="Next", command=show_subjects).grid(column=2, padx=10, pady=10)

master.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't actually work. When trying variables["Subject 1"] it gives me whatever is displaced on the dropdown box not what is actually selected by the user if that makes sense. Instead of displacing math ext as chosen by the user it just displaces math adv. Not quite sure what else I can do? I need it to once I click 'next' all the users selections will be collected.I also get( AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get') when trying to use variables["Subject 1"].get()

Comment: I am able to do variable.get() but this only collects the last dropdown box not all of them.

Comment: @ZacharyAmbrose Provided an example which works for me.